# Get redirect url for an image file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the redirected URL for an images stored in the S3. Due to some CORS issues, I've tried to do it with an AJAX call and JSONP. But I get an issue:

```
Refused to execute script from '...' because its MIME type ('image/jpeg') is not executable.
```

**I don't want to open the file or follow the redirect. I only need the URL.**

```
function getRedirect(url) {

var settings = {
          'cache': false,
          'dataType': "jsonp",
          "crossDomain": true,
          "url": url, 
          "method": "GET",
          "headers": {
              "accept": "application/json",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
          }
      };
      
$.ajax(settings).success(function (result,status,xhr) {
  var r = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
  console.log(r);
  return r;
});

};
```

Comment: You need to do this server side

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself because I do not have time to set up a redirecting service.

```js
fetch(url, {
  redirect: 'manual',
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response.url);
});
```

Comment: Thx, doesn't work because of '...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource....'

Comment: I've added  {mode: 'no-cors'} without success

Comment: That is not up to you. If the server does not do CORS or you are not calling from an allowed server (localhost is normally not) then you will need a proxy. Sounds like a good idea anyway

Comment: response.url is the origin url!